# Conditional / why we put pp after if?

Tags: conditional-constructions, irrealis-mood

> Yep, all these men keep laughing because it looks like rape and sexual assault. If I personally would have seen that. I would have punched that dude in mouth. That dog has seen its last days. Just sayin

Why after "If" the speaker says "would have seen" and not simply the past simple "saw"  ? What is the difference ?

Is it because the speaker wants to assert his words or emotions? 
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an *irrealis* use, what traditional grammar calls a 'subjunctive': specifically a "condition contrary to fact". The speaker did not in fact see the men laughing but speaks of what he would have done if he **had** seen it. *If I would have seen* is not acceptable in formal registers, which does not allow ordinary modal uses of *will/would* in *if* (condition) clauses; you should write:

> If I personally ***had seen*** that I would have punched that dude in mouth.

But it is the standard way of expressing a past irrealis with any modal in a consequence clause, and especially in AmE colloquial speech (which this clearly is intended to represent) it is very common in condition clauses as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply , its so helpful but as far as I know in many grammar books we should say "If I personally saw that ..." Although I never actually saw anything ... Am I right here ? If yes  then what is the difference with " Had seen" thank you again

Comment: @GamalThomas In a counterfactual situation "If I saw" would have **present** irrealis reference; that is excluded by the **past** irrealis in the consequence clause "I **would have punched**".

Comment: Correction: it is **a** standard way of expression a past irrealis for some speakers, particularly in American English. Many speakers, including me and I think most Brits, would never use "would have" in an "if" clause.

Comment: @ColinFine It does seem to be less common in the BrE vernacular; though that depends somewhat on how you parse "If PRONOUN'd 'a VERBen". I suspect that many of the *would have*s like this we see are either tacit expansions or hypercorrections of the new subjunctive clitic *'da*. ... In any case, I'll fold your observation into the answer.